# Firestore add another map to an array field in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am working on a front end project with React and Firebase.

I would like to create a database where registered users can save their recipes by clicking on the RecipeCard button.
However with a click on another card, the contents of the field are overwritten and not added to the main recipeDb array.
Is there a solution?

[here the img of my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrRck.png)

And here the code:

```
const dbFavorites = (e) => {
const recipeDb = [
  {
    Recipe: title,
    Id: id,
    Source: source,
  },
];
fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    const dbAdd = fire
      .firestore()
      .collection("User-favorites" + user.uid)
      .doc(user.uid)
      .update({ recipeDb });
  }
});
```

};

The function dbFavorites is used in the button:

```
<button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          dbFavorites();
        }}
      >
```

I state that FieldValue.arrayUnion gives me an error and I don'have a backend...

**Update**: I tried to use arrayUnion in this way (instead of the previous function):

```
const dbFavorites = (e) => {
const recipeDb = [
  {
    Recipe: title,
    Id: id,
    Source: source,
  },
];
fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    const dbAdd = fire
      .firestore()
      .collection("User-favorites" + user.uid)
      .doc(user.uid)
      .update({ fav: fire.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(recipeDb) });
  }
});
```

};

Comment: What error to be specific ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj The error is: "Cannot read property 'arrayUnion' of undefined"

Comment: Can you share that part of code so we can see why array union did not work ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj update!